# Cannot parse response body content in katalon studio

Tags: parsing, groovy, katalon-studio, jsonslurper

I’m facing a problem, where I can’t parse response body content.

Here is what I use for parsing, that works for another responses but for current response it doesn’t work.

```
String getContent = get_response.getResponseBodyContent()
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(getContent)
```

And it gives me a following error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a JSON array in your response body content. Try this one:

```
List parsedJson = slurper.parseText(getContent)
```

or just

```
def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(getContent)
```

Detailed example:

```
def json = """
[
    {
        "companyName":"Foo",
        "customerId":"Bar"
    },
    {
        "companyName":"Foo2",
        "customerId":"Bar2"
    }
]
"""
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
//Map mapJson = slurper.parseText(json) FAIL!!!
List listJson = slurper.parseText(json)
def objJson = slurper.parseText(json)

objJson.each { map ->
    println(map)
}
```

Output:

```
[companyName:Foo, customerId:Bar]
[companyName:Foo2, customerId:Bar2]
```

Comment: Now, I getting another error. 

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [id]
Possible solutions: get(int), get(int), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), grep(), grep()

Comment: Probably it's because you are trying to access a value by string key in `parsedJson` which is a list. If this is the case try this `parsedJson[0]["companyName"]`. This way you will access `companyName` of the first element in the parsed json

Comment: Thanks, that works well ! But why does not work Map for my case ?

Comment: You can see on your screenshot that you have a JSON array surrounded by square brackets `[{...}]`. More info can be found at [JsonSlurper doc](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html#json_jsonslurper). Also, if you declare a variable type Groovy tries to cast the right hand side expression to that type

Comment: @Dmitry, I am trying the similar one with the proposed solution. However, I am unable to filter the content and print it out. Any suggestions, please ?

Comment: my json :
[
  {
    "Name": "Apol1",
    "Title": "Apol1",
    "Domain": "apollo1.com",
    "DCs": [
      "Email add",
      "hints"
    ],
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IsActive": false
  },
  {
    "Name": "Apol2",
    "Title": "Apol2",
    "Domain": "apollo2.io",
    "DCs": [
      "Email add",
      "Phone"
    ],
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IsActive": false
  },
  {
    "Name": "Apollo3",
    "Title": "Apollo3",
    "Domain": "apollo3.com",
    "DCs": [
      "Email add",
      "Pws"
    ],
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IsActive": false
  }
]

Comment: Any ideas, how can I get all the names and all the DCs ?

Comment: @user1911509 If I got you right, you can retain `Name` and `DCs` in the resulted `List` of `Map`. Try this `objJson.each { map -> map.retainAll { k, v -> k in ['Name', 'DCs'] } }`. If you want to print the result you can either print as you go after `retainAll` statement or in a dedicated `objJson.each { map -> println(map) }` after the aforementioned `objJson.each {...}`